# Firestore Rules - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app that will connect Caretakers (users) with their Children via a Family.  The Family data structure is like so:

```
/families/idFAMILY {
  id: 'idFAMILY',
  name: "Smith',
  caretakers: {
    idPARENT1: "true",
    idPARENT2: "true"
  },
  children: {
    idCHILD1: "true",
    idCHILD2: "true"
  }
}
```

(where everything in caps starting with id...  is an autogenerated ID)

Using Angularfire, I'm trying to get a list of families for the current user using this query:

```
const path = 'caretakers.' + userId;
const famCollection = this.afs.collection('families', ref => ref.where(path, '==', 'true')).valueChanges()
```

But I'm getting the "Missing or insufficient permissions" error and I can't figure out why.

My rules are:

```
function isCaretaker(familyId, userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/families/$(familyId)).data.caretakers[userId] == 'true';
}
match /families/{familyId} {
  allow create: if userExists();
  allow read, write: if isCaretaker(familyId, request.auth.uid);
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the IDs holding a boolean true or a string "true"

Comment: Is `idPARTENT1: "true"` set to the string "true" or the boolean `true`?

If it's the boolean, make sure your query and your rules also use the boolean value.